# matplotlib wont show a picture ubuntu

Tags: matplotlib

im on the ubuntu 17.04 daily build and im trying to use matplotlib like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import PIL
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as plt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import *



    #plt.imshow(iar)
    #plt.show

    def threshhold(imageArray):
        blanceAr = []
        newAr = imageArray

        for eachRow in imageArray:
            for eachPix in eachRow:
                print eachPix

                i = Image.open('images/numbers.0.1.png')
                iar1 = np.asarray(i)

                i2 = Image.open('images/numbers.y0.4.png')
                iar2 = np.asarray(i)

                i3 = Image.open('images/numbers.y0.5.png')
                iar3 = np.asarray(i)

                i4 = Image.open('images/sentdex.png')
                iar4 = np.asarray(i)

                fig = plt.figure()
                ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=3)
                ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,0), rowspan=4, colspan=3)
                ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,3), rowspan=4, colspan=3)
                ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (4,3), rowspan=4, colspan=3)

                ax1.imshow(iar1)
                ax2.imshow(iar2)
                ax3.imshow(iar3)
                ax4.imshow(iar4)

                plt.show()
threshhold()
```

Im trying to make a Neural network img scanner but im having trouble!
When i run this theres no error and no popup, please help!

Comment: In your example, `threshhold()` is defined but never invoked.   How is it called?

Comment: even when the command was out of the loop and the img was too it wouldnt do. i tried calling it and still nothing

Comment: Yes, you tried calling it but you haven't shown that code here.  For example, what did you pass to `threshhold()` when you called it?  If the `imageArray` argument was an empty array, or a list of empty rows, I owuld expect that behavior.  Please show the entire, unabridged code example that exhibits the behavior you describe.

Comment: there, put it in

Comment: No, this could not be the code that you tested.  This would yield an error because `threshhold()` expects one argument and you are passing none.  Please share the exact code that you tested.  If you tested this, then the error you got is because there's no `imageArray`.

Comment: but heres the weird thing, there IS no error....